# Selectively Skip Newline Depending on Context

Tags: antlr

I must parse files made of two parts. In the first one, new lines must be skipped. In the second one, they are important and used as a delimiter.

I want to avoid solutions like http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1734 and use predicate instead.

For the moment, I have something like:

```
WS:     ( ' ' | '\t' | NEWLINE) {SKIP();};
fragment NEWLINE : '\r'|'\n'|'\r\n';
```

I tried to add a dynamically scoped variable `keepNewline` that is set to true when "entering" second part of the file.

However, I am not able to create the correct predicate to switch off the "skipping" of newlines.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier than you might think: you don't even need a predicate.

Let's say you want to preserve line breaks only inside `<pre>`...`</pre>` tags. The following dummy grammar does just that:

```java
grammar Pre;

@lexer::members {
  private boolean keepNewLine = false;
}

parse
 : (t=. 
    {
     System.out.printf("\%-10s '\%s'\n", tokenNames[$t.type], $t.text.replace("\n", "\\n"));
    }
   )* 
   EOF
 ;

Word
 : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+
 ;

OPr
 : '<pre>' {keepNewLine = true;}
 ;

CPr
 : '</pre>' {keepNewLine = false;}
 ;

NewLine
 : ('\r'? '\n' | '\r') {if(!keepNewLine) skip();}
 ;

Space
 : (' ' | '\t') {skip();}
 ;
```

which you can test with the class:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PreLexer lexer = new PreLexer(new ANTLRFileStream("in.txt"));
    PreParser parser = new PreParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.parse();
  }
}
```

And if `in.txt` would contain:

```
foo  bar
<pre>
a

b
</pre>


baz
```

the output of running the `Main` class would be:

```
Word       'foo'
Word       'bar'
OPr        '<pre>'
NewLine    '\n'
Word       'a'
NewLine    '\n'
NewLine    '\n'
Word       'b'
NewLine    '\n'
CPr        '</pre>'
Word       'baz'
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It is indeed much easier than what I have been trying to do...^^